# add new columns with conditions to a dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I create a dataframe df_energy :

```
df_energy=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Demonstrator/Downloads/power.csv', delimiter=';', parse_dates=[0], infer_datetime_format = True)
```

with this structure :

```
 df_energy.info()
```

> ```
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 43229 entries, 0 to 43228
> Data columns (total 6 columns):
> TIMESTAMP        43229 non-null datetime64[ns]
> P_ACT_KW         40376 non-null float64
> PERIODE_TARIF    43209 non-null object
> P_SOUSCR         37501 non-null float64
> SITE             43229 non-null object
> TARIF            43229 non-null object
> dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(2), object(3)
> memory usage: 2.0+ MB
>
>
> TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR SITE TARIF 
> 2015-07-31 23:00:00 12.0 HC NaN ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 
> 2015-07-31 23:10:00 466.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 
> 2015-07-31 23:20:00 18.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 
> 2015-07-31 23:30:00 17.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5
> ```

As I am starting learning python, I would like to know can I add three new columns : High_energy, Medium_energy and low_energy .

High_energy contains the P_ACT_KW value if P_ACT_KW > 400,  Medium_energy contains the P_ACT_KW value if P_ACT_KW is between 200 and 400, Low_energy contains the P_ACT_KW value if P_ACT_KW < 200.
For example :

> ```
> TIMESTAMP P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF P_SOUSCR SITE TARIF High_energy Medium_energy Low_energy
> 2015-07-31 23:00:00 12.0 HC NaN ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0 0 12
> 2015-07-31 23:10:00 466.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 466 0 0
> 2015-07-31 23:20:00 18.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0 0 18
> 2015-07-31 23:30:00 17.0 HC 425.0 ST GEREON TURPE_HTA5 0 0 17
> ```

Thank you

Kind regards

Comment: No  they are 6 : 2015-07-31 23:30:00 | 17.0 | HC | 425.0 | ST GEREON | TURPE_HTA5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [np.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) from [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) as:
Sample df:

```
Out[71]: 
             TIMESTAMP  P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF  P_SOUSCR       SITE  \
0  2015-07-31 23:00:00      12.0            HC       NaN  ST GEREON   
1  2015-07-31 23:10:00     466.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
2  2015-07-31 23:20:00      18.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
3  2015-07-31 23:30:00      17.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   

        TARIF  
0  TURPE_HTA5  
1  TURPE_HTA5  
2  TURPE_HTA5  
3  TURPE_HTA5

df['high_energy']=np.where(df['P_ACT_KW']>400,df['P_ACT_KW'],0)

df['medium_energy']=np.where((df['P_ACT_KW']>200)&(df['P_ACT_KW']<400),df['P_ACT_KW'],0)

df['low_energy']=np.where(df['P_ACT_KW']<200,df['P_ACT_KW'],0)

Out[72]: 
             TIMESTAMP  P_ACT_KW PERIODE_TARIF  P_SOUSCR       SITE  \
0  2015-07-31 23:00:00      12.0            HC       NaN  ST GEREON   
1  2015-07-31 23:10:00     466.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
2  2015-07-31 23:20:00      18.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   
3  2015-07-31 23:30:00      17.0            HC     425.0  ST GEREON   

        TARIF  high_energy  medium_energy  low_energy  
0  TURPE_HTA5          0.0            0.0        12.0  
1  TURPE_HTA5        466.0            0.0         0.0  
2  TURPE_HTA5          0.0            0.0        18.0  
3  TURPE_HTA5          0.0            0.0        17.0
```

Comment: Another question please : Is it possible to use "np.where"  for more than 1 condition , for example if (x< ..) else if (y <...), else .....?

Comment: yes it is possible using nested np.where like `np.where(cond,value,np.where(cond1,value,value))`.